# Call to undefined function curl_init() for Magento TAF

Tags: magento, netbeans, selenium, wamp

I'm trying to get Selenium to work with Magento TAF in Netbeans off a Wamp Server. When I run the test I get the following error:

> Call to undefined function curl_init() in
>   C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\pear\PHPUnit\Extensions\SeleniumTestCase\Driver.php
>   on line 995

When I try and do a google search I keep getting results saying to enable curl, which is pointless for me because I do have it enabled. Have had it enabled for quite some time. The information in from the phpinfo for the curl section is as follows:

### curl

- cURL support: **enabled**
- cURL Information: **7.24.0**
- Age: **3**
- Features

  - AsynchDNS: **Yes**
  - Debug: **No**
  - GSS-Negotiate: **Yes**
  - IDN: **No**
  - IPv6: **Yes**
  - Largefile: **Yes**
  - NTLM: **Yes**
  - SPNEGO: **No**
  - SSL: **Yes**
  - SSPI: **Yes**
  - krb4: **No**
  - libz: **Yes**
  - CharConv: **No**
- Protocols: **dict, file, ftp, ftps, gopher, http, https, imap, imaps, ldap, pop3, pop3s, rtsp, scp, sftp, smtp, smtps, telnet, tftp**
- Host: **i386-pc-win32**
- SSL Version: **OpenSSL/0.9.8u**
- ZLib Version: **1.2.5**
- libSSH Version: **libssh2/1.3.0**

On line 995 of the file I have the following line:

```
$curl = curl_init();
```

When I ctrl+click the function in phpstorm I get taken to:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PhpStorm
>
> 5.0.4\plugins\php\lib\php.jar!\com\jetbrains\php\lang\psi\stubs\data\curl.php
>   and on that line i have

```
function curl_init ($url = null) {}
```

Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: If you create a new php file simply with `$ch = curl_init();`, does it generate an error? If so, then I would suggest that curl is not properly installed.

Comment: @Lock do you mean creating the .php file and running that in a browser cause i did that, just a white page

Comment: Yep- as in create a blank PHP page to test the functionality of curl with something like this: `<?php $ch = curl_init(); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "www.google.com"); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); $output = curl_exec($ch); print_r($output); ?>`. See if that works.

Comment: @Lock copied the code and i got "302 Moved
The document has moved here. " with "here" linking me to google, that is what i'm supposed to get

Comment: Yes thats right, which suggests there is no issue with your cURL support. You don't by any chance have 2 copies of PHP running with different configuration files? A blotched install of WAMP that is installed, without cURL support? I don't use PHPStorm, but my guess is it has a built in PHP server that references a different PHP.ini file as to the one that your Magento website is using.

Comment: @Lock it seems that Wamp uses a different php.ini file as there was a php.ini file that had curl commented out yet the php.ini file i access in wamp had it uncommented, after your comment about running different config files i did a text search thought all of my computer for "extension=php_curl.dll" and found the multiple .ini files, some with it commented, i uncommenetd them all and after it started to work (somewhat) i began to trace back to find out which file was the problem

Comment: Great. I'll add this as a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that your IDE is referencing one php.ini, whilst when you run your tests on your WAMP server, it is referencing another.

Either:

a) Make sure you are using the same pho.ini file between the IDE and the WAMP server, or;

b) Make sure all php.ini files have `extension=php_curl.dll` uncommented.